# declare-fun and define-fun in Z3 can't work together?

Tags: z3, theorem-proving

I need to model length of array. So I declare a function

```
(declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int)) Int)
```

At the same time, I want to define some macros using `define-fun`.

However, as I tested a little bit on Z3, it seems that `define-fun` and `declare-fun` can't exist at the same source file?

This code like following works fine:

```
(define-fun mymax ((a Int) (b Int)) Int
  (ite (> a b) a b))

(assert (= (mymax 100 7) 100))
(check-sat)
```

(src: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/jRzs)

But the following, no matter where the `LEN` inserted, there will be errors:

```
;(declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int) Int) 
;unknown sort 'assert'  
(define-fun mymax ((a Int) (b Int)) Int
  (ite (> a b) a b))
; (declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int) Int) 
;unknown sort 'assert'
(assert (= (mymax 4 7) 7))
; (declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int) Int) 
;;unknown sort 'check-assert'
(check-sat)
;(declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int) Int) 
 ;invalid sort, symbol, '_' or '(' expected
```

(src: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/HdEy)

Does anybody know how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare-fun` and `define-fun` can be used together. 
The problem is that you have a missing parenthesis.
It should be

```
(declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int)) Int)
```

instead of

```
(declare-fun LEN ((Array Int Int) Int)
```

Because of the missing parenthesis, the second is actually declaring a function `LEN` with two arguments (array and integer), then Z3 generates an error when it can find the resulting sort for this declaration.

Here is a link to the complete example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/TjNS